# How to solve Rails environment difference? Works in staging but not in dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have dashboards that are in a backbone.js app in a larger Rails app. In staging and production (on heroku) the dashboards work fine.

However, in my local Pow dev environment I get the following error in the browser console when I try and view a specific dashboard:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'merge'
```

After tracking that down a bit, here is what I came up with. The merge method being referred to in the error message is coming from the rendered /assets/templates/dashboard/details.js file. Here is the code with what the browser is calling the error at the start of line 5: helpers = this.merge...:

```
(function() {
  this.HandlebarsTemplates || (this.HandlebarsTemplates = {});
  this.HandlebarsTemplates["dashboard/details"] = Handlebars.template(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
  this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];
helpers = this.merge(helpers, Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};
  var buffer = "", stack1, functionType="function", escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;
  buffer += "<p>\n  <b>Name:</b>\n  <span class='editable' data-attribute-name='name'>";
  if (stack1 = helpers.name) { stack1 = stack1.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}); }
  else { stack1 = depth0.name; stack1 = typeof stack1 === functionType ? stack1.apply(depth0) : stack1; }
  buffer += escapeExpression(stack1)
    + "</span>\n</p>\n<p>\n  <b>Description:</b>\n  <span class='editable' data-attribute-name='description'>";
  if (stack1 = helpers.description) { stack1 = stack1.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}); }
  else { stack1 = depth0.description; stack1 = typeof stack1 === functionType ? stack1.apply(depth0) : stack1; }
  buffer += escapeExpression(stack1)
    + "</span>\n</p>\n<p>\n  <button class='add_module'>Add module</button>\n</p>\n";
  return buffer;
  });
  return this.HandlebarsTemplates["dashboard/details"];
}).call(this);
```

I think this is a Rails precompile or asset pipeline setup issue since it works fine in staging and production but fails in local development.

It sucks having to push any changes to heroku to test them. Any suggestions for solving this are appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have not checked what is passed in options. I am not sure how to get that. How do you suggest I test it? I was focusing on the environment differences since the same code works in staging but not in dev. The content that should be getting passed is very similar and I tested empty and filled out dashboards.

Comment: Actually the error only shows in the chrome web console. there are no errors in the Rails app. Is there a way to better debug in the Rails app with no error or get more details from the browser console?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. But what could change between staging and local dev environments to change what can be merged or not? As far as I can tell there are no other differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is resulting from my handlebars version being out of date. Thanks to the Thoughtbot guys for helping to track this down.

https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/547